# Proxy activate in Instagrapi

Tags: python, instagrapi

How can I set proxy without username:password in Instagrapi?
I used like this:
cl.set_proxy('socks5://anylogin:anyPass@185.215.53.253:3629')
or
cl.set_proxy('socks5://:@185.215.53.253:3629')
And received errors.
Free Proxy provider sais that there is no need to use username and password